# Rails, how to create functional tests for apis using minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, testing

I have a rails app that has api controllers for providing restful api. The api controllers are located at       `app/controllers/api/v1/controllers.rb`

Say I have a controller called tweets_controller.rb, its in
`app/controllers/api/v1/tweets_controller.rb`, Besides the api controller, I also have a tweets_controller for the web server, in
`app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb`. According to the [rails testing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html), I know how to create tests for web server's tweets_controller in `test/controllers/tweets_controller_test.rb`, but how can I create tests for the api controllers?

I tried create the file   `test/controllers/api/v1/tweets_controllers_test.rb` but when I ran the test, an error occured said

`Don't know how to build task '/test/controllers/api/v1/tweets_controller_test.rb'`.

I searched on the web and most of the results are about RSpec, I want to learn how to minitest before move to RSpec.

Comment: Testing api controller is no difference than testing regular controller. How do you test your controller ? **bin/rake test test/controllers/api/v1/tweets_controllers_test.rb** ? Can you post your **test/controllers/api/v1/tweets_controllers_test.rb** ?

Comment: @Yen-Ju I run my test for regular controller by running `rake test test/controllers/tweets_controller_test.rb`, with no problem. And for api, I run `rake test test/controllers/api/v1tweets_controller_test.rb` and the mentioned error occurs.

Comment: OK, turns out its my typo. I run with the command `rake test /test/controllers/api/v1tweets_controller_test.rb`. The "/" before test is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out its my typo. I run with the command `rake test /test/controllers/api/v1tweets_controller_test.rb`. The "/" before test is unnecessary.